# changes made in scss don't work

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

When I run gulp it recognizes any changes made in any scss file. It even minifys it into a style.min.css within a css folder which is within the build folder and the site refreshes on my localhost.

My issue is that none of the changes I make inside the scss files actually happen on the website though. If I make changes in the style.css file and manually refresh the site, it updates with the same changes made.

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
   return gulp.src('./sass/style.scss')
      .pipe(plumber(plumberErrorHandler))
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(autoprefixer({
         browsers: ['last 2 versions']
      }))
      .pipe(cssnano())
      .pipe(rename('style.min.css'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass', 'scripts'], function (){
   gulp.watch('./sass/*.scss', ['sass']);
   gulp.watch('./js/*.js', ['scripts']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are watching the path `./sass/*.scss`, I assume you have a subfolder within this `./sass/` folder.

Your partial files are imported because you can see the change when editing the main style.scss stylesheet.

The problem lies in the watch task that is only watching the folder named *sass* but it also has to watch the subfolder and its .scss contents. ex:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass', 'scripts'], function (){
    gulp.watch('./sass/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('./js/*.js', ['scripts']);
});
```

the `/**/` makes sure any subfolder and its contents are also watched.

Comment: I don't have a subfolder within ./sass/

it goes project/sass/style.scss which imports _header.scss etc which are located in the exact same spot.

my style.css is just project/style.css there is nothing in that file as of now.

anything I put in the scss files compiles into a minified css file in a project/build/css/style.min.css but none of this actually makes changes to my wordpress site

anything I code in style.css makes changes to the actual website when I refresh it, but nothing goes into the styles.min.css. That is how it's supposed to be though I think right?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the part where you said "and the site refreshes on my localhost" could you post the gulp task named browserSync?

Comment: You know what, can you somehow send me your folder structure + gulpfile? (ex. pastebin)

Comment: I can't upload files on pastebin, can I email it to you?

Comment: Sure, mail it to mike@duister.me

Comment: thanks! I'll send a compressed file to you in a few min